# remove view duplicate data in sql database

Tags: sql, database, view

```
SELECT ticket_id, thread_type, FROM ost_ticket_thread WHERE thread_type='M'
```

this is my sql statement. the result from the sql statement like below.

```
-----------------------
|ticket_id|thread_type|
-----------------------
|4        |      M    |
|4        |      M    |
|5        |      M    |
-----------------------
```

How i want to view data without the same ticket_id and thread_type?
i have done the `group by` statement. but i have encounter a problem when i want to count all ticket_id. it should be 2. but it return 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT ticket_id, thread_type
FROM ost_ticket_thread 
WHERE thread_type='M' 
GROUP BY ticket_id,thread_type
```

**OR**

Use `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ticket_id, thread_type
FROM ost_ticket_thread 
WHERE thread_type='M'
```

Result:

```
TICKET_ID   THREAD_TYPE
4           M
5           M
```

Sample result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a84f3/4).

**EDIT:**

For the getting the count:

```
SELECT ticket_id, thread_type,COUNT(ticket_id) as Count
FROM ost_ticket_thread 
WHERE thread_type='M' 
GROUP BY ticket_id,thread_type
```

Result:

```
TICKET_ID   THREAD_TYPE   COUNT
4           M             2
5           M             1
```

Comment: thanks for the helping. i have done it. but i have a problem when i want count all ticket_id that have thread_type='M'. it also count the same value

Comment: @user3487681: See the edit in my answer. Feel free to accept the answer if you are satisfied so that it could help others who come across with the same type of doubts in future.

Answer (score 0):

Use this query

```
SELECT distinct(ticket_id), thread_type, FROM ost_ticket_thread WHERE thread_type='M';
```

this will work